# Singleton shared resource using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, singleton

I have a web page that allows users to upload multiple files associated with a record.  Originally the page would upload each file one at a time and tied up the UI Thread while the upload took place.  It was refactored to use web workers.  A WorkerPool was created to manage the threads that each worker was run in.  For example if I was uploading 20 files and the pool is setup to have 8 threads (based on the machines cores) then the first 8 uploads would happen right away and the remaining 12 are added to a queue.  Each time a file upload completes the thread is free'd and the pool assigns another upload from the queue to that thread to be executed. The idea being that I would have no more than 8 web workers uploading files at a given time.

Everything was working as planned then I realized the other day that the WorkerPool is actually getting created for each Page the user has opened and isnt actually global.  Because the WorkerPool is not globally shared and is instead created anew for each page, if the user starts and upload and it finishes but they dont close that tab and start uploading in a different tab then rinse and repeat for multiple tabs the computer is continually generating new threads for the web workers chewing up resources.

What I'm looking to do is make the WorkerPool global to the entire domain like https://localhost

Its been explained to me that React Context and such is tab specific.  I've looked at localstorage but that doesnt appear to due what I want unless I'm not understanding how it could be used in this context.

Coming from Java i'm use to the idea of a singleton using getInstance() which I implemented in my WorkerPool but it didnt work as intended.

My WorkerPool Code as of now

```
import WorkerTask from './WorkerTask'
import WorkerThread from './WorkerThread'

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
export default class WorkerPool {
  private static instance: WorkerPool
  // set some defaults
  taskQueue : WorkerTask[]
  workerQueue : WorkerThread[]
  poolSize: number

  constructor(poolSize: number) {
    this.poolSize = poolSize
    this.taskQueue = []
    this.workerQueue = []
    this.init()
  }

  public static getInstance():WorkerPool {
    if (!WorkerPool.instance) {
      WorkerPool.instance = new WorkerPool(window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency)
    }
    return WorkerPool.instance
  }

  public addWorkerTask(workerTask: WorkerTask) {
    if (this.workerQueue.length > 0) {
      // get the worker from the front of the queue
      const workerThread = this.workerQueue.shift()
      if (workerThread) {
        workerThread.run(workerTask)
      }
    } else {
      // no free workers,
      this.taskQueue.push(workerTask)
    }
  }

  public init() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.poolSize; i++) {
      this.workerQueue.push(new WorkerThread(this))
    }
  }

  public freeWorkerThread(workerThread: WorkerThread) {
    if (this.taskQueue.length > 0) {
      // don't put back in queue, but execute next task
      const workerTask = this.taskQueue.shift()
      if (workerTask) {
        workerThread.run(workerTask)
      }
    } else {
      this.workerQueue.unshift(workerThread)
    }
  }
}
```

My Page that needs the WorkPool to add upload task to it currently gets the Worker Pool like this

```
import WorkerPool from '@src/webworkers/WorkerPool'

  const workerTask = new WorkerTask(handleFileUploadProgress, handleFileUploadError, WorkerType.Upload,
      {
        nameBase: nameBase,
        file: { transfer: [file] },
        name: file.name,
        fileTags: tagMap[file.name] ?? {},
        metadataId,
        timeoutLength: UPLOAD_TIMEOUT_LENGTH,
        url: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:9100' : `${window.location.origin}`,
      })
  WorkerPool.getInstance().addWorkerTask(workerTask)
```

Comment: Are you experiencing actual slowdowns or are you optimizing unnecessarily?  in the javascript world its not usually necessary to worry too much about memory leaks etc unless youre doing something obviously bad.  You could use localStorage to share some data between tabs but thats it.  You can definitely share one instance of this WorkerTask across the application without re-instancing it.  However if the user opens a separate tab then thats viewed as another instance of the entire application so the class would be re-instanced.  Not sure if any of this was helpful.  I think I need more info.

Comment: Not experiencing slow downs atm.  Its more of an optimization. From watching our user's utilize our site they tend to create records and upload files across multiple tabs.  Scenario I've seen is a user creates a record uploading files which spawns up to 8 web workers.  Because they are uploading large files they start creating a new record (this takes time) in a new tab while the files are being uploaded for the first record. If they open 8 tabs creating new records there are now up to 64 web worker threads just sitting there chewing up resources assuming the user doesn't close the tab.

Comment: Did a bunch of analysis yesterday to see if the idle web workers were causing issues when tons of tabs were open and from what I can tell they aren't so looks like it might not be an issue I need to address at the moment.